# Addition in exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we compute $x$ if
$$4^x+4^{x+1}+4^{x+2}=7^{x+1}-7^{x-1}$$
The solution belongs to the interval $(-2,2]$, but how do we arrive at it?

Comment: Hint: re-write as $4^x\times \left(1+4+4^2\right)=7^x\times \left(7-\frac 17\right)$.

Comment: I want to say that it's from the interval.

Comment: Only................$x=2$.

Comment: Ok, but the problem from the test asks you to determine the interval to which $x$ belongs. The offered answers are all intervals. That's the solution I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Following suggestion given in the comments by lulu, from

$$4^x+4^{x+1}+4^{x+2}=7^{x+1}-7^{x-1}\iff 4^x\times \left(1+4+4^2\right)=7^x\times \left(7-\frac 17\right)\\\iff \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^x=\frac{\left(7-\frac 17\right)}{\left(1+4+4^2\right)}$$

then use logarithm.